# Ionic / Cordova trigger app action when app isn't in foreground

Tags: android, ios, cordova, angular, ionic-framework

## Original Question (Listen to hardware buttons press)

I am wondering if it is possible to listen to the hardware buttons of a phone using Ionic / Cordova. 
The important thing is that this should also work when the user is not currently using the app like somehow through a background service? 
**Basically I want to take a screenshot when the user presses the volume down and the power button at the same time in a hybrid app using Ionic.** The app then offers to edit that screenshot or save it directly.

I have done some research and found the [cordova events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#volumedownbutton) to listen to those buttons. I also read that the pause event should be fired when the power button is pressed. Anyhow, I don't think listening to those events would work outside of that app?

## Original Question Conclusion

After some more research I conclude that this is not really possible using Cordova / Ionic. Even the native implementations of this problem seem to be more of a hack than a clean solution. The reason for this is, that the app currently on top should have the control of handling the various button events. You could interfere with another app and you always need to run a background service.
 Anyhow, all the solutions I saw seem too dirty for me.

## Updated Question / Reevaluation of the problem

> **Basically I want to take a screenshot when the user presses the volume down and the power button at the same time in a hybrid app
> using Ionic.**

If I can't solve the current problem I have to rethink it. So: 
**Actually, I just want the user to have the ability to take a screenshot in a way that offers a good usability experience.**

There are various ways I can do that as an alternative to pressing two hardware buttons simultaneously.

**Option 1:** User presses a button "Take screenshot" -> the app goes in the background, a screenshot is taken from the underlying app, the app comes back to the foreground. 
AFAIK this wouldn't even work in iOS, only Android offers a "draw on top of other applications", so in iOS the screenshot would simply be taken from the home screen in all cases...?

**Option 2:** User presses a button "Take screenshot" -> the app goes in the background and a notification is pushed.

- This notification could say "Tap to take a screenshot". The notification panel (which is always drawn on top of other applications) disappears, the screenshot is taken and the app pops up. This could be done using [Local Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/#on) and listening to the on clear, cancel etc. events.
- The notification could even have custom buttons using [OneSignal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/) (see [Action Buttons](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/action-buttons)). One button could say "Add screenshot", another one could say "Done", so the user could even take multiple screenshots at once.

**Option 3:** A button could be added to the shortcuts that triggers the take a screenshot action. I don't know if that is even possible and if that works on all devices.

I would say the best solution would be to go with Option 2: Custom Action Buttons on a Notification. Notifications should be a must have on all devices and should always be drawn on top of the current app. So the user just swipes down the notifications and presses a button to take a screenshot.

**I don't really have any prior knowledge to this topic so I would be glad if somebody could confirm or improve my thinking process.**

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I have done a bit of research into this, mainly just to satisfy my own curiosity. I came across this plugin

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/blob/master/README.md

It allows you to carry out task in the background.

Please note this from the readme file.

> ### Store Compliance
>
> Infinite background tasks are not official supported on most mobile operation systems and thus not compliant with public store vendors. A successful submssion isn't garanteed.
>
> Use the plugin by your own risk!

This probably isn't a big deal on Android but there is an open issue with regards to Apple app store submissions being rejected. Read through the issue to see how others over one this.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/122

**Original Answer:**

If you want to take a screenshot there is this plugin:

https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot/blob/master/README.md

Maybe you could listen for some other events whilst using the pause listener. If they are activated then using the screenshot plugin referenced above call:

```
navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
    if(error){
        console.error(error);
    }else{
        console.log('ok',res.filePath);
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer to included information about the screenshot plugin.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have tried to see the problem from a different perspective and updated the question.